# Creating a user, mapping to a database and assigning roles to that database using SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server

I need to create Logins and Users automaticaly per SQLCMD - is this possible?

Creating the Logins works:

```
SQLCMD -E -S LOCALHOST\ERP  -Q "CREATE LOGIN [%%i] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[demo]"
```

But I did not found a way to create the users within the demo DB:

I tried:

```
SQLCMD -E -S LOCALHOST\ERP  -Q "USE [demo]"
SQLCMD -E -S LOCALHOST\ERP  -Q "CREATE USER [%%i] FOR LOGIN [%%i] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]"
SQLCMD -E -S LOCALHOST\ERP  -Q "ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [%%i]"
```

((%%i is the variable for the user)

I read that the reason is that SQLCMD always is opening a new session. Is there a way to do everything in one session?

You maby asking why I'm using SQLCMD - the reason is that i build a look to create up as many users as Need. (e.g. 1000)

Comment: SQLCMD is invoking a new session because you're calling it multiple times. Each call is a new session. Put all your statementsinto one call, or use an input file. Statements are terminated by a semicolon(`;`), so you can run a command like: `USE Demo; CREATE USER TestUser FOR LOGIN TestUser; ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER TestUser;` That will run all 3 statements in a single batch.

Comment: Considering, however, that you're doing 1000 users, I suggest creating an input file and passing by by using the `-i` switch.

Comment: THANKS ALOT THIS WORKED:

    FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2,3 DELIMS=; " %%i IN (c:\UA_Liste.txt) DO (
    
    SQLCMD -E -S LOCALHOST\ERP  -Q "CREATE LOGIN [%%i] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[Demo Database NAV (11-0)], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[German];USE [Demo Database NAV (11-0)];CREATE USER [%%i] FOR LOGIN [%%i];ALTER USER [%%i] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo];ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [%%i]"
    )
    pause
UA_LISTE.txt is the List of Users.